# Where does magento store its cached images?

Tags: magento, caching

I know that magento resizes the original product images and caches it multiple times with different sizes according to its need.

1. Where are those chached images stored (path)?
2. Are they the ones that will get deleted when you flush image cache from cache management?
3. If I were to manually cache some images, where would I have to put them in order for them to get deleted when you clear cache from cache management?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. All cached images saved in `BaseUrl/media/catalog/product/cache` folder
2. Yes
3. Checkout the `BaseUrl/media/catalog/product/cache` folder you will get your answer

Comment: hmm ok, so what gets put in the var/cache/ folder then?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to add images on cache folder, Magento does the same automatically.

Comment: I'm implementing some complex modules and I am resizing images for certain views, I obviously want to save the thumbnails somewhere and don't want them to be left there forever, because it is a dynamic website, with changing content (which shop isn't?). When you delete any custom module item associated with an image, sure, any other image related to it goes away, but I also want to be able to fix unexpected problems with clear cache.

Answer (score 2):

The answer here is resized images are already saved separately to the normal cache, in media/catalog/product/cache not in  var/cache/.

If you look in System > Cache Management you will see there is a separate button for clearing just those images, so if you really need to clear image cache use that button.